# ASP.NET Rendering usercontrols with codebehind

Tags: asp.net, rendering, webusercontrol

I want to render a usercontrol dynamicly but my code doesn't work as expected. The codebehind won't be executed. Here is my code for rendering:

```
Dim ucControl As UserControl = LoadControl(pControl.VirtualPath & "/" & Control & ".ascx")

Dim ucSB As New StringBuilder
Dim ucSW As New StringWriter(ucSB)
Dim ucHTML As New HtmlTextWriter(ucSW)

ucControl.RenderControl(ucHTML)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: try these links 
    http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/3/asp.net/create-a-control-in-the-codebehind-and-retrieve-its-rendered-output , 
 http://forums.asp.net/t/983500.aspx/1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553118/why-dont-my-user-controls-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering a UserContorl the normal lifecycle events are not called. This behavior is by design.

You could cast the UserControl to your type and call the methods explicitly:

```
Dim ucControl As MyUserControl = Ctype(LoadControl(pControl.VirtualPath & "/" & Control & ".ascx"), MyUserControl)

ucControl.Page_Load(me, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Comment: Well, I just made a public Sub in my control for now, which I'm calling at Page_Load and at the dynamic rendering. Its possible to call the sub if you define the usercontrol object just as object. 

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add the dyncamically loaded control to your page as early as possible in the page lifecycle, so that the event wil be called.